# Getting a derived property's data from a parent object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have two user objects, Student and Professor. Each user can have their own settings, which looks like this:

```
public class PersonSettings
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public PersonSettingsValues Settings { get; set; }
}

public class PersonSettingsValues
{
    public bool NotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class StudentSettingsValues : PersonSettingsValues
{
    public int GymPassTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class ProfessorSettingsValues : PersonSettingsValues
{
    public bool AllowOfficeHours { get; set; }
}
```

Some settings are shared, but Students and Professors also have their own settings, so I have inherited models.

I'm just storing the settings as json in the database by using conversion values on PersonSettings:

```
builder.Property(ps => ps.Settings).HasConversion(
    s => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
    s => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonSettingsValues>(s, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));
```

So the PersonSettings table is populated with several records with settings, some have the data in the Settings column formatted as StudentSettings and others are ProfessorSettings

What I'd like to do is have an endpoint that will return StudentSettings for a Student. I have:

```
[HttpGet("{personId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStudentSettings([FromRoute] Guid personId)
{
    var personSettings = await _context.PersonSettings
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(ps => ps.PersonId == id);

    return Ok(personSettings);
}
```

The problem is that the Settings property is populated with only the PersonSettingsValues, I don't get the StudentSettingsValues with it. I'm not sure how to make it do that.

I tried using a DTO instead and mapping to it with AutoMapper:

```
public class StudentSettingsDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public StudentSettingsValues Settings { get; set; }
}

...

[HttpGet("{personId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStudentSettings([FromRoute] Guid personId)
{
    var personSettings = await _context.PersonSettings
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(ps => ps.PersonId == id);

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<StudentSettingsDTO>(personSettings));
}

...

CreateMap<PersonSettings, StudentSettingsDTO>()
    .ForMember(ps => ps.Settings,
        o => o.ResolveUsing(s => (StudentSettingsValues)s.Settings));
```

In my mapping, I'm just trying to cast the Settings as a StudentSettingsValues type, but I get an error saying

> Unable to cast object of type 'PersonSettingsValues' to type 'StudentSettingsValues'

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, how can I just return a PersonSettings object with either StudentSettings or ProfessorSettings on it?

Comment: I've never used automapper, so I will just throw out some ideas.  What does personSettings.GetType().Name return if you know it's a Student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your builder, when parsing the json from database, parses to PersonSettingsValues. Once that's done, you lose all the other data. You have a few options:

1. Not sure what this builder exactly is and how much custom logic you
   can add. But if at the time of deserialization you know if it's
   professor or student, you should deserialize to object you need.
   Then even if you assign it PersonSettingsValues  you will still be
   able to cast it later on to a more concrete type.
2. Instead of different models, make interfaces. IPersonSettingsValues,
   IStudentSettingsValues, and IProfessorSettingsValues. And then have
   just one model that implements all of the interfaces. Then your
   deserializer can serialize to that one model. The values that don't
   exist will go to default, but it will always be deserialized. And
   then when you want to use it from specific context, you will be able
   to cast it to a specific interface.
3. Deserialize to a dynamic object(thus it just deserializes whatever is in the json), and then use autoMapper to map dynamic object to a concrete type.

If it's not clear, tell me and I will try to come up with a code example.